# Help me prove this inequality with positive real numbers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Prove that $$p(qr+s+1)(rs+p+1)(sp+q+1)+q(pq+r+1)(rs+p+1)(sp+q+1)+r(pq+r+1)(qr+s+1)(sp+q+1)+s(pq+r+1)(qr+s+1)(rs+p+1)>(pq+r+1)(qr+s+1)(rs+p+1)(sp+q+1)$$ provided that $p,q,r,s$ are positive real numbers for which $p,r>1$ and $q,s<1$. $$ $$ So far I realised that I can divide both sides of the inequality by $(pq+r+1)(qr+s+1)(rs+p+1)(sp+q+1)$ and I got $$\frac{p}{pq+r+1}+\frac{q}{qr+s+1}+\frac{r}{rs+p+1}+\frac{s}{sp+q+1}>1$$ $$$$ I'm not sure how to proceed now or what may lead me to the solution. I will be very grateful for any help on how to solve it.

Comment: You are almost there! Hint: how can you change a little bit of every one of the four terms on your LHS so that they sum to one?

Comment: @NeatMath I'm sorry but I don't know what exactly I should change. I tried to look for something useful but failed

Comment: Just do the most obvious: change the first term to $\frac{p}{p+q+r+s}$ and prove it is smaller than $\frac{p}{pq+r+1}$. Similarly for other three.

Comment: @Neat Math  Are you sure?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{p}{pq+r+1} = 1+ \sum_{cyc}\left( \frac{p}{pq+r+1} - \frac{p}{p+q+r+s} \right)\\
= 1+ \sum_{cyc}\frac{p(s+p+q-pq-1)}{(pq+r+1)(p+q+r+s)} \\ 
= 1+ \sum_{cyc}\frac{p(s+(p-1)(1-q))}{(pq+r+1)(p+q+r+s)} > 1.\blacksquare
$$

Comment: Why the last inequality is true?

Comment: $s>0$, and $p, r>1, q, s <1$

Comment: I posted this solution $19$ hours ago and deleted my post . You are right of course!